# pppd: using the noauth option requires root privilege

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, pppd

I have a user `username` who is member of group `dip`. I'm trying to run `/usr/sbin/pppd`, which is mode `-rwsr-xr--`, owner `root`, group `dip`, as user `username`. However, I get the error message: `/usr/sbin/pppd: using the noauth option requires root privilege`

Is there some way to go around that, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the man page for pppd:

```
noauth
Do not require the peer to authenticate itself. This option is privileged.
```

So it appears that you have to have root privilege to use that option. Just because your user is allowed to run pppd, does not mean that the user is privileged to do everything that pppd can use.

Why can't you run it with root privileges?

Comment: Well, I can. I just did not want to in my specific case.

Comment: Right, right. Well, if you can find a way to use it sans the privileged options, you can get away with it. I'm not sure what your use case is, exactly.